# Displaying various pandas dataframe at screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm manipulating data using Python 2.7 in Jupyter. A common thing needed is to look at (meaning "displaying at screen") a vector coming from a DataFrame, to compare with another vector, sometimes from another DataFrame. I've been trying, searching the web and stackoverflow, but I haven't found away.

Example : let's say I have those two df:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,61).reshape(-1,6),columns=list('abcdef'))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(61,1,-1).reshape(-1,6),columns=list('ghiklm'))
```

I would like to be able to compare, say df1['b'] and df2['k'], displaying in my worksheet the two columns side by side, something like

```
[df1.loc[:,['c']], df2.loc[:,['i']]]
```

but not one after the other, like this:

```
c     i
2     58
8     52
14    46
20    40
26    34
32    28
38    22
44    16
50    10
56     4
```

Could someone help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is same `index` of both `DataFrames` use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (pd.concat([df1.c, df2.i], axis=1))
    c   i
0   3  59
1   9  53
2  15  47
3  21  41
4  27  35
5  33  29
6  39  23
7  45  17
8  51  11
9  57   5
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly well!!!! what about df not having the same number of rows?

Comment: Then use reset_index like `print (pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True).c, df2.reset_index(drop=True).i], axis=1))`

Comment: The reset_index worked perfectly, thank you very much! I've "accepted" your answer. :)